# Can I programm an app on Phonegap with a mysql database on a another destination?

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, phonegap-build

I'm making an app with html,css,javascript and I want to use PhoneGap to make the app avalible on the appstore + playstore but I read that php is not working inside Phonegap and that the only thing working on both platforms is javascript. Can i use Ajax to access my databases some where in the net from the index.html file in my PhoneGap www folder?

I was concidering to simply use iframe and display my site like that but then i cant use the native camera or get access to the memory etc. then again, there is a way with something called cross domain messeging or somthing like that but the security issue seems hugh to me, right? Or should I consider making everything as a usual webpage (which is mobile responsive) and try it with the HTML iframe?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to create your Bussiness Logic on your Server and expose it through Web Services. Then with simple AJAX Calls from your "App" you will be able to accomplish anything you like.

Comment: Yes, typically you can make a REST or SOAP server type setup to handle this.

Comment: generally speaking, you do NOT expose your database to the internet. and you especially don't connect to the db directly from a client app. That'd leave you WIDE OPEN to a compromise since you couldn't tell if it's your code sending a query or someone who's extracted the db credentials from the app and is doing queries directly themselves. Your app talks to a web service, and that service handles the DB communications.

Comment: how can i avoid this from happening? @MarcB

Comment: you stop working on your project and learn basic defensive programming techniques for web apps first. security isn't something you slap on later. security is something you have to bake into the system during the design phase.

Comment: sorry but you are talking to someone who is able to do simple if and echo stuff in php, what do you mean by business logic on my server? i got a usual mysql db and php7 running on the server (1and1.com) I was thinking of just switching the php in my code to ajax @Strahdvonzar

Comment: @MarcB I'm still programming and planning and stuff but javascript is something new to me and i know that php is serverside and java client side (so no one can grab that stuff from the client side) but i just need to know how this ajax thing (the middle thing between javascript and php) can be secure from beeing read out by inspecting sourcecode for example :O

Comment: you can't secure it. anything that executes in the browser, by definition, is under the user's control and can be accessed, no matter what you do to try and prevent it. that's why you DON'T put your business logic on the client. e.g. if you were building an ecommerce site, you don't let the client send over `200" flatscreen tv, $0`. you ONLY send `200" flatscreen tv`, and look up the price PURELY ON THE SERVER.

Comment: Okay so ajax is still clientbased than, is it somehow possible to let user input, in for example forms, to be send somehow to an other site on my webserver which makes the changes to my database? to make it simple: 
User clicks in my options on button which says i want email notifications(inside the webpage in Phonegap) and this get somehow send to my something.php page on my webserver which connects to my database and changes the db entry to "true email notification"... (my pseudocode hehe) ??? @MarcB

Comment: ajax is just a completely standard/normal HTTP request, that happens to be performed in the background the page, on behalf of code, instead of the user clicking on a link. that's it.  the main benefit is that you're not forcing a full reload/rebuild of the page, as a click on a normal `<a href=...>` does, or submitting a form. but the actual browser-server communications are essentially IDENTICAL to having submitted a form or clicking on a link.